# Getting the number of weeks per month base on 2 dates

Tags: php

I have 2 dates like this `2018-08-12` until `2018-12-31`

I wanted to get the number of `weeks` per `month` base on the dates given,

My wanted output would be like this:

```
Array
(
  [18 Aug] => 3,
  [18 Sep] => 4,
  [18 Oct] => 4,
  [18 Nov] => 4,
  [18 Dec] => 4
)
```

Is this possible using 2 dates to get the number of `weeks` per `month`?

This is my attempt:

```
$start = strtotime('2018-08-12');
$end = strtotime('2018-12-31');
$dates = array();
while ($start <= $end) {
  $dates[date('y M', $start)] = round(($end - $start) / 604800);
  $start = strtotime("+1 month", $start);
}
```

But my result would be like this:

```
Array
(
  [18 Aug] => 20,
  [18 Sep] => 16,
  [18 Oct] => 11,
  [18 Nov] => 7,
  [18 Dec] => 3
)
```

Comment: How did you get these numbers? Full August-2018 - almost 5 weeks, from August 18 to September 1 - less than 2

Comment: Just a sample sir, but that is the output I wanted.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll get a same "just a sample" code, if you don't explain the logic of your result

Comment: @splash58 okay ill add my code

Comment: @splash58 question is updated

Comment: Why 18th every month?

Comment: @DusanRadovanovic ohh! sorry, actually that is year, 18 means 2018 sorry

Comment: How did you get 3 for August?

Comment: @DusanRadovanovic `August 12` to `August 31` is 3 weeks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question right, you can do it by a little more complicated loop, running from the end to the start and substructing previous value

```
$start = strtotime('2018-08-12');
$end = strtotime('2018-12-31');
$cur = strtotime(date('Y-m-', $end) . date('d', $start));
if ($cur > $end) $cur = strtotime("+1 month", $cur);

$dates = array();
$save = 0;
while ($cur >= $start) {
    $temp = round(($end - $cur) / 604800);
    $dates[date('Y M', $cur)] =  $temp - $save;
    $save = $temp;
    $cur = strtotime("-1 month", $cur);
}
// Just if you want an ascending order of months
$dates = array_reverse($dates);
```

[**demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/55b139f0bb9e199c25ca8be1b0236958854a3a5d)

Comment: Yeah this is abit complicated but I works so thanks alot